# Passing values from code behind into JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a script function which is getting values from html input controls.

**Demo.js**

```
function clickLogin() {
    var szIP = $("#loginip").val(),
    szPort = $("#port").val(),
    szUsername = $("#username").val(),
    szPassword = $("#password").val();

    if ("" == szIP || "" == szPort) {
       return;
    }

    var iRet = WebVideoCtrl.I_Login(szIP, 1, szPort, szUsername, szPassword, {
        success: function (xmlDoc) {
        showOPInfo(szIP + " login success！");

            $("#ip").prepend("<option value='" + szIP + "'>" + szIP + "</option>");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#ip").val(szIP);
                getChannelInfo();
            }, 10);
        },
        error: function () {
            showOPInfo(szIP + " login failed！");
        }
    });

    if (-1 == iRet) {
        showOPInfo(szIP + " login already !");
    }
}
```

These values are html input control on my asp page. I want to pass this html control values from code behind in js function .

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(scriptKey))
    {
        i = i + 1;
        scriptKey = scriptKey + i;

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), scriptKey, "clickLogin();", true);
    }
}
```

I have debugged in every possible way I could and I got to know that html input controls is not having any value when it passed in js. I don't understand how will this work.

And I want this all task on post back only not for the first time load

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    loginip.Value = row[0].ToString();
    username.Value = row[1].ToString();
    password.Value = row[2].ToString();
    port.Value = row[5].ToString();   
}
```

Here is what loginip conrol is -

```
<tr>
            <td class="tt">IP address</td>
            <td><input ID="loginip" type="text" class="txt" runat="server"  /></td>
            <td class="tt">Port</td>
            <td><input id="port" type="text" class="txt" runat="server"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tt">User name</td>
            <td><input id="username" type="text" class="txt" runat="server"  /></td>
            <td class="tt">Password</td>
            <td><input id="password" type="password" class="txt" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
```

the code was working fine when I was calling js function from login button in aspx file  as it submit the http request.

Problems now are -
1. This http control are not having any values when js function is called from backend.
2. I want to submit httprequest without any button click. To be more specific through a masterpage treeview node.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It appears that editor @Omar removed `string script = "clickLogin('"+loginip.Value + "','"+port.Value+"','"+username.Value+"','"+ password.Value + "');";` from this question. If that was important, please edit it back in. See [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50696662/revisions).

Comment: if loginip is ta textbox isnt the propery supposed to be loginip.Text="";

Comment: I am sorry sir Halfer. Next time i will choose my words very carefully.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier.. I have added code to easy understanding of what this input controls are. and loginip is the IP address of the camera.

Comment: Yes @halfer, sorry.